# Need solution with UIPickerView

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview

There is the thing, I have segmented control in my view, and when user switch between it, I want my `UIPickerView` to change it rows (For example `SegmentedControl` index 0, my rows is centimeter and kilogram, when index is 1 it change to inches-pound).

So, I think about 2 ways to achieve that, first - I may have add 2 `UIPickerView`, so I can set either one hidden when I need to, but I guess default methods for picker view don't expect to work with 2 pickers. Or, is it possible to, I have to dynamically change values when user tap segmented control.

What should I do to achieve the point?

Comment: you want to change the pickerview selected row or entire pickerview ?

Comment: Entire, i mean titles of rows

Comment: for that take two array of values when you switch the segment controller then change the picker array to new array based on your condition and reload the picker view with new array values as i mensioned  in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change the values when your segment value change

use below code

when segment 0 selected

```
[Array removeAllObjects];
[Array addObject:@"centimeter"];
[Array addObject:@"kilogram"];
[pickerVw reloadAllComponents];
```

when segment 1 selected

```
[Array removeAllObjects];
[Array addObject:@"inches"];
[Array addObject:@"pound"];
[pickerVw reloadAllComponents];
```

here array is your array from where you get pickerview's raw value
and pickerVw is your object of UIPickerView

Comment: Thank you Pratik that will do

Answer (score 1):

try with this one when you change the segment control value at that time change the selected row in pickerview.

```
[pickerView selectRow:n inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

if you want to change the picker view components then reload  the picker view with different value.

```
[pickerView reloadAllComponents];
```